# Wallet recovery phrase

Tags: blockchain.info, mnemonic-seed

Due to a copying error the last word of my 12 word mnemonic recovery phrase for blockchain is missing.

Just wondering if anyone knows of any software that could generate words and automatically test them out to see if they work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the seedrecover.py script in [btcrecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/)

You will need to have the master public key (xpub), a receiving address generated from the seed, or an addresses database.  seedrecover.py will then check all the seed variations to see if they derive the specified key or address.

Comment: your question is very short, and links to a "foreign" webpage. Maybe you can shortly describe what needs to be done, and put the link to the end?

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested the best option is to try the [Seed Recovery](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/blob/master/docs/Seedrecover_Quick_Start_Guide.md) script from btcrecover.

You just need to run the python script, which will ask you for the words you know (those eleven words) and then you also need one of these two:

- An address that you know it is from the wallet you are trying to recover.
- A full node running on your computer so the script can check out each wallet it generates until it finds one with non-negative balance.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.